# D3.js: Starting animations when a section is in view

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a page that has several D3 charts that aren't visible until the user scrolls down to that section of the page. The charts have some basic animations that I'd like to only take place when the section a chart is in comes into view. The only luck I've had is when I use a mouseover event on the div a chart is sitting in like so:

```
d3.select("#chapter1_2")
  .on("mouseover", function() {

    svg.selectAll("rect.bar")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.pct); })

  });
```

In other words, when the user moves the mouse over the #chapter1_2 div, the bars animate to their desired length. Clearly, using the mouseover event isn't the most reliable approach, so I'm looking for something else that might help.

I've tried using graph-scroll (https://1wheel.github.io/graph-scroll/), but that doesn't really work because there's only one transition that takes place for each chart and that transition fires the moment any of the divs within a chapter/section get classed as active, which happens immediately on page load.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why not use `scroll` and check the chart offset vs the scroll position?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I actually think I managed to get around this in combination with graph-scroll: I now have a function that checks to see if the div it sits in has the class "graph-active-scroll", and when it does it fires the animation!

Comment: Great! Please add your solution as an answer for future users or remove this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it to work in conjunction with graph-scroll (https://1wheel.github.io/graph-scroll/) using the following:

```
    var gs = graphScroll()
        .container(d3.select("#container"))
        .graph(d3.selectAll("#chart1_2))
        .sections(d3.selectAll("#chapters > div"))
        .on("active", function() { 
            if (document.getElementById(chapterID).className == "graph-scroll-active") {

                svg.selectAll("rect.bar")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.var3); });

        }});
```

Most of this can be figured out with the graph-scroll documentation, but the portion that made it work for me was the function in the .on("active") section - I have it checking the relevant explanatory text in the div with ID = containerID. Once graph-scroll deems it active, the function checks to see if the "graph-scroll-active" class has been applied. If it has, then the transition fires.

Answer (score 0):

I think using jquery you can achieve it in a more reliable way:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        var elemID = $(elem).attr("id");
        var elemTag = $(elem).prop("tagName");

        return elemTop <= docViewBottom &&
            elemBottom >= docViewTop &&
            elemTag == "svg"
            ? elemID
            : false;
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $("svg").each(function () {
            var ele = isScrolledIntoView(this);
            if (ele) {
                var ele_ = ele.replace(/-/g, "_");

                var fn = eval(ele_);
                var checkEle = $("#" + ele).attr("data-enable");

                if (!checkEle) {
                    //   console.log(ele);
                    $(this).attr("data-enable", "true");
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        fn();
                    }, 300);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    // function that starts drawing d3 chart 
function id_of_svg() { // id name written with underlines
   // d3 codes 
}

}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
     <svg id="id-of-svg" width="100%" height="400"></svg>
</div>
```